# Find $\ker(T)$ where $T(\begin{bmatrix}a_{11}&a_{12}&a_{13}\\a_{21}&a_{22}&a_{23}\end{bmatrix})=a_{12}x^4+a_{22}x^2+a_{11}+a_{23}$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces, linear-transformations

Find $\ker(T)$ where $T(\begin{bmatrix}a_{11}&a_{12}&a_{13}\\a_{21}&a_{22}&a_{23}\end{bmatrix})=a_{12}x^4+a_{22}x^2+a_{11}+a_{23}$

$T:M_{2,3}(\mathbb{Z}_5)\to P_4(\mathbb{Z}_5)$, where $\mathbb{Z}_5$ is $\{0,1,2,3,4\}$

---

$\ker(T)=\{M\in M_{2,3}(\mathbb{Z}_5)|T(M)=0x^4+0x^3+0x^2+0x+0\}$

Hence we must have that $a_{12}=0,a_{22}=0$

$(a_{11}+a_{23})=0\to \color{red}{a_{11}=-a_{23}}$

---

So I would rewrite my matrix as follows:

$\begin{bmatrix}a_{11}&a_{12}&a_{13}\\a_{21}&a_{22}&a_{23}\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}-a_{23}&0&a_{13}\\a_{21}&0&a_{23}\end{bmatrix}$

**But my textbook does it another way, and I don't know how it reaches these values**

[image]

Where did it get the $4a_{11}$ from? Why is $a_{11}$ just $a_{11}$ in this case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$a_{11} + a_{23} = 0 \ $ if and only if $a_{23} = 4a_{11} \ $ because you are working in $\mathbb{Z}/5$. You have done the same thing, except you wrote $-1$ instead of $4$. They are the same mod 5 so it doesn't matter which you use.